# Redgate Profiler ASP .NET Understanding the results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, profiling

I am Profiling a .NET ASP page. Its got a masterpage and telerik controls. It loads the data from a seperate web project with Services. I've debugged the services with SoapUI and they take 2.5 seconds to run 6 service calls.  The page loads in around 12 seconds. I have to run two profiler instances to debug the Main Web App and the Service app with SQL calls. From what I can see the Service code takes 3 to 4 seconds to run.  I need to know what to look for to find the real issue. The 8 or 9 seconds its taking the main page to load outside of the service calls.

Main Web App
Where does the code go for 9 seconds?
[image: Main Web App]

So I expand the methods without source - This is probably where I need help. How do I find what I need to fix here? There a several places where the wall clock time goes from a large time to almost nothing.
[image: methods without source]

Web Service App SQL
The SQL timings are strange to me. It shows 3 calls, but one has actual inputs. I debugged the code and its not calling the Service 3 times. The first result timings are very large. No matter what I do in soap UI its never that long and I've run them from the VisualStudio Debugger and they are not that long.
[image: Web Service App SQL]

Web Service App Methods
This shows that no significant time is spent on any of the service code.
[image]

Soap UI- running the service call - on the longest DB Call
1.6 seconds on the longest call
[image: Soap UI- running the service call - on the longest DB Call]

Service\Database Profiling from SoapUI Call
1.6 seconds in Soap = 1.49 seconds in profiler. So that makes sense, Though i still have no clue what the multiple method calls and the time to first record = 4.49 is about.
[image: Service\Database Profiling from SoapUI Call]

Comment: Wow, interesting question. Did you check web traffic using Fiddler?

Comment: I just found the problem. I started stripping the pages apart, piece by piece.  A Telerik Control is taking 8+ seconds to render..  The method databinds the control and leave the method. Then i goes to never never land for a while.  But why can't I see that in the results?

Comment: No idea. But I'm glad you found the reason. What will you do? Will you replace that control?

Comment: I found they are loading 7k records into a treeview. I am going to filter it properly or replace it.  Also, I'm not closing this question. Because I want to understand why i can't see this in the profiler. Is is a bug or a configuration issue?